# About -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections and --gc-sections options

Tags: gcc, x86, arm

In my ARM project, I use following to build os-less application binary:

```
arm-linux-gcc -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -o boot.o boot.S
arm-linux-gcc -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -o main.o main.c
arm-linux-ld -T link.lds --gc-sections -o target.bin boot.o main.o
```

These works fine. Because If I remove "-ffunction-sections", "-fdata-sections" and "--gc-sections" options, the target.bin file size will increase nearly twice..

But on the x86 platform, same method, I found that:
If I don't use those gcc and ld options, the output is normal, but the output file will be 0 byte if I use those options as arm platform.

Answer (score 2):

`-Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections` and `--gc-sections` should work on x86 system. Are you sure your program and your linker script are suitable for x86 ? As your program is meant for bare-metal ARM, it probably does not have entry points for your x86 OS, and if there is no entry point, everything is garbaged by `--gc-sections` option.

BTW, your "question" actually enclose no question.

Comment: Thanks. The 0-byte output is just the question. I re-define the entry point, and it works.

Comment: But I found another problem in x86 gcc. If I use -Os option, the generated binary runs abnormal. If I don't add -Os option, the output binary size is larger, but it runs normally. Did you meet such problem? I will debug this when I have time.

Comment: I did meet such kind of problem, it isn't always the same cause, so I can't help you here, but it's often related to a C undefined behavior (there are so many undefined behaviors in C...), which may change with optimization level.